# Querying selected fields based on a list of string from database/model in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, orm

I am trying to create a GraphQL resolver using Python. I need to select only those columns from the database that the user has requested. I have the requested column names as a list of strings.

How do I query only those columns on that model using SQLAlchemy
I tried the following, but that didn't work:

```
......
query = session.query(MyModel)
query = query.options(Load(MyModel).load_only(*requested_columns))
result = query.all()
```

Unfortunately this code is not working. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, I don't think you need to call `Load(My Model)` because it is implied by `query(MyModel)`. Have you tried simply: `query.options(load_only(*requested_columns))`?